# Decoding from Base36 to decimal in C#

Tags: c#

```
public static Int64 Decode(string input)
        {
            var reversed = input.ToLower().Reverse();
            long result = 0;
            int pos = 0;
            foreach (char c in reversed)
            {
                result += CharList.IndexOf(c) * (long)Math.Pow(36, pos);
                pos++;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I am using a method to decode a value from base36 to decimal. The method works fine 
but when I get to decode the input value of "000A" then things start to go wrong and it
decodes this as -1.

Can anyone see what's going wrong? I am really confused with the code and how it works.

```
private const string CharList = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Comment: Actually, it looks fine to me. What does `CharList` look like?

Comment: @leppie - No, that's correct. For `pos=0`, you'll get `1`, which gives you `1*value` (where `value` is just the position) for the least significant character. For `pos=1` you'll get `36`, which gives you `36*value` for the next least significant character, etc.

Comment: Oooops! 5 minutes to weekend.

Comment: I see your edited question: look at @Polynomial answer because it's the one for you! You're using `IndexOf(c)` where c is lowercase while your CharList is uppercase!!

Comment: Using Math.Pow() is also a really bad idea.  Use the [homework] tag on questions like these.

Comment: Yeah, bitwise shifting left (<<) would be much more efficient and accurate.

Comment: @Polynomial: Bitshifting would require the base to be a power of 2, which 36 is not. (I have no idea if you can decompose it in to 32 then say 4, I leave that for the math boffins)

Comment: @Leppie - You're correct. I'm not with it today! The most accurate solution would be to use `long` and multiply in a loop, since this avoids casting to double.

Comment: @Polynomial: It's weekend, everyone is allowed to think sideways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `ToLower()` on your source and your list contains uppercase chars only, so `IndexOf('a')` returns -1.

I think you'd want to use `ToUpper()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I can only assume that your `CharList` does not contain `A`, therefore `IndexOf(c)` returns `-1` to show that the character wasn't found. Keep in mind that `IndexOf` is case sensitive by default, so if you're using lowercase in your `CharList` and uppercase for `c`, it won't match.

```
// pos = 0
result += CharList.IndexOf(c) * (long)Math.Pow(36, pos);
// pos = 36^0 = 1
// CharList.IndexOf(c) gives -1 when not found
// therefore, it equates to:
result += -1 * 1
```

Comment: Actually it's the contrary: c is lowercase but CharList is uppercase; anyway your answer was correct! Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive function:

```
using System;

class Program {
   static int decode(string sIn, int nBase) {
      int n = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".IndexOf(sIn[^1]);
      string s = sIn[..^1];
      return s != "" ? decode(s, nBase) * nBase + n : n;
   }

   static void Main() {
      var s = "q3ezbz";
      var n = decode(s, 36);
      Console.WriteLine(n == 1577858399);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can succinctly perform this task with Linq and avoid having a CharList at all & support converting from any base (2 to 36) to base 10 as follows:

```
string b36 = "000A", tbase = 36;
int b10 = b36
       .Select(d => d >= '0' && d <= '9' ? d - '0' : 10 + char.ToUpper(d) - 'A')
       .Aggregate(0, (pos, d) => pos * tbase + d);
```

For completeness (to go from base 10 to any base):

```
int value = 10, tbase = 36;
string result = "";
while (value > 0)
{
    int x = value % tbase;
    result = (char)(x >= 0 && x <= 9 ? x + 48 : x + 'A' - 10) + result;
    value /= tbase;
}
Console.WriteLine(result.PadLeft(4,'0'));
```